# Is EU Single Market membership part of the backstop?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Is EU Single Market membership part of the backstop in the Withdrawal Agreement?

Comment: I guess this question can have different answers depending whether one interprets membership as full membership or just some level of access. I assumed the former (much shorter answer, ha ha). If someone wants to give you the full details on the latter...

Comment: I briefly mentioned some of those issues in an older answer https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/39453/18373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. *A* customs union doesn't equal the [Single Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market). Not even *the* [Customs Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Customs_Union) equals that. Turkey is such [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union%E2%80%93Turkey_Customs_Union). Crucially, the Single Market includes freedom of movement for labor, which is not included in the Customs Union.

Under the backstop Northern Ireland will basically apply the full code of *the* Customs Union, while the rest of the UK will be in *a* less encompassing one.

Comment: There are also some extra conditions on services (e.g. electrical supply) of Northern Ireland under the backstop, which place it closer to the single market.

Comment: @Relaxed: does the backstop include freedom of movement of EU labor (not just Irish) into Northern Ireland?

Comment: Not downvoting because the answer is correct. But Turkey's position is not exactly enviable from a trade deal standpoint, and insofar as I'm aware there are some parts of the Single Market that still apply, like food safety or fishing rights (and if I am not mistaking submitting to the ECJ for those things).

Comment: @Fizz I don't think so, why are you asking?

Comment: @Relaxed: because that (freedom of movement for labor) was the main difference I was trying to convey here. Like I said in a comment under the question, it's also reasonable to assume that by "membership" he meant just some level of Single Market access (or possibly even some level of harmonization), but I assumed he meant full membership.

Comment: @Fizz The backstop is not about "some" level of access, it's about whatever level of "regulatory alignment" is necessary to avoid checks at the border. I don't know if that amounts to "full membership" (whatever that means) but that goes beyond a customs union. Northern Island would be in a very different situation than Turkey. Your answer completely obscures that fact.